# Unstable internet speed macbook

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, performance, macbook, ping

In our network 4 computers and AP:

- MacBook Pro
- Notebook Dell
- 2 PC
- wifi access point Zyxel Keenetic 4G.

PC connect to Zyxel with cable, notebooks - with wifi.

Sometimes users of MacBook and notebook complains of slow network performance.

I try to ping this notebooks and sow unstable ping. But devices connected with cable ping normal.

I run ping on my PC.

- First window - MacBook
- Second window - Dell notebook
- Third window - Zyxel access point

[image]

Why MacBook has unstable pings? How can I fix this and make users happy?

Comment: See [12 Tips for Troubleshooting Your Internet Connection](http://www.pcmag.com/slideshow/story/262550/12-tips-for-troubleshooting-your-internet-connection) and  
[How to Fix Your Wi-Fi Network: 7 Tips](http://www.pcworld.com/article/260524/how_to_fix_your_wi_fi_network_7_tips.html)

Answer (score 0):

Those unstable ping times aren't your problem. MacBooks use 802.11 Power Save mode. With a typical ping interval of 1 second, the receiver keeps going to sleep between pings.  If you had real traffic going on, the receiver wouldn't go to sleep in the middle of it, so you wouldn't have this latency.

Keep looking for the source of the slowness. You haven't found it yet.